# How to run internal (Neo)Vim ":Command" from external Terminal?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, macvim

I'm using MacOSX, and I have script on Terminal, and since I will probably forget how to update everything inside Vim/NeoVim, is it possible to pass command, e.g. `:PlugUpdate`, to `nvim`/`vim` so that I can update all things (Terminal `Homebrew`, `Vim-Plug`, etc) at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a command when starting up with `-c` (or `+`):

```
vim -c 'PlugUpdate'
```

You may also want to pass `qall` if you are running this from a script.

Comment: I searched `vim -h` and found `-c`, but I didn't find out `qall`, what does it mean?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn’t clear. I meant also passing `-c 'qall'` i.e. the ex command `:qall` to quit all vim windows afterwards (otherwise your script will open but not close vim).

Comment: Can I pass multiple command than just `PlugUpdate`?

Comment: @job_start Yes you can.  You can either do `vim -c 'PlugUpgrade' -c 'PlugUpdate' -c 'qall'`, for example, or `vim -c 'PlugUpgrade | PlugUpdate | qall'`.